# Search the second nth-of-type in the whole page?

Tags: jquery, css

This [page](http://clo2015.chineselearnonline.com/lessoncontent/lesson-004-hints-and-tips/) has two `.button-group` elements. I wanted to remove the second one so I did this:

```
$('.button-group:nth-of-type(2)').hide()
```

The element is not being removed, though.

The buttons are in their own sections and different divs. Could that be the problem? If so how to target the second `.button-group` of the whole page?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.eq(n)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) where `n` is the number of an element starting from `0`. So to get the second element you need to use `$('.button-group').eq(1).hide();`. Here is the snippet:

```js
$('.button-group').eq(1).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-group">1st group</div>
<div class="button-group">2nd group</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
$('.entry-content .button-group').hide()
```